# I have a follow up on "How exactly does ROM work when the power is turned off?"

Tags: rom

The answer to the [above question](https://superuser.com/questions/1203774/how-exactly-does-rom-work-when-the-power-is-turned-off) says that

> ROM typically stores data as wires that are either physically connected or physically disconnected

What I want to know is how these `wires` are connected and disconneted? And how can the ROM be reprogrammed then, because connecting and disconnected them would require mechanical switches (maybe something else, that I am not aware of). If we do not use a mechanical switch and rely on high current to melt the wire(like a fuse) then we cannot reprogram it. So how does that work?

Comment: [ROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory) cannot be reprogrammed. Period.

Comment: Read past the first sentence and you will get an idea of the answer.

Comment: The likely occurrences of ROM today: (1) in a SoC the ROM is hardcoded in the silicon at time of chip fabrication (along with all the other chip logic circuits), aka mask ROM. (2) a marketing misuse of the term "ROM" in descriptions of smart phones and tablets, and actually refers to the (protected and semipermanent) firmware stored in (rewriteable) Flash memory, a type of EEPROM.

Comment: @zx485 Yeah. I understand that now. I thought that both EEPROM and ROM were same with the added feature in the former that it is reprogrammable. I am reading the Digital Logic and Circuit Design by Morris Mano. It explained the working of ROM and mentioned all the types of ROMs available. EEPROM was listed under there, which is why I thought they are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of ROM, Read Only Memory, is that it is not rewritten. If it is reprogrammable then it is *not* ROM.

There are [EEPROMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EEPROM), Electrically Erasable Programmable Read Only Memories, which can be erased, then programmed, and then become ROM.

> EEPROMs are organized as arrays of floating-gate transistors. EEPROMs can be programmed and erased in-circuit, by applying special programming signals. Originally, EEPROMs were limited to single byte operations, which made them slower, but modern EEPROMs allow multi-byte page operations. An EEPROM has a limited life for erasing and reprogramming, now reaching a million operations in modern EEPROMs. In an EEPROM that is frequently reprogrammed, the life of the EEPROM is an important design consideration.
>
> [image]

Flash memory is (broadly speaking) a type of EEPROM.

Comment: From an electronics background they are two very distinct things. ROMs are very definitely not reprogrammable beyond whatever process wrote to them in the first place. Programmable ROMs (PROM) were definitely single use and if you made a mistake it got thrown away. They were, as you mentioned, programmable fuses and you could only go one way. You could, in theory write to it multiple times if all you were wanting to do was blow more fuses but you could never "unwrite" a bit. EPROM and EEPROMs let us repeatedly erase and write again by using transistors and FETs as above.